# Getting strings from a list into VID in Red language

Tags: list, user-interface, rebol, red

I am trying to create a panel with dynamically created gui elements:

```
  sentlist: ["A" "B" "C"]
  main: function [slist] [
    view collect [
      keep [below]
      repeat i length? slist [
        keep[
            text slist/i    ; THIS STEP IS NOT WORKING
            field "" ] ] ] ]

  (main sentlist)
```

A series of strings is sent to the function for putting text labels from it. The GUI window/panel is opening all right but text elements do not have any label on it. Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sentlist: ["A" "B" "C"]
main: function [slist] [
    view collect  [
        keep 'below
        repeat i length? slist [
            keep  compose [text (slist/:i) field "" ]
        ]
    ] 
]
main sentlist
```

Comment: By the way, this is the official formatting. Don't edit/deface it always. I do not understand that your editing of the formatting is accepted by reviewers

Comment: I had tried `slist/:i` but not with parens `(slist/:i)` and also without `compose`. Can you provide some explanation about need for parens and compose keyword in your answer. Regarding the formatting, I do not think it is logical to keep closing braces on separate lines. Blocks of code are best seen by indentation and not closing braces/brackets.

Comment: I think it is logical. You see with ease and without counting closing brackets, if there is a missing bracket or more brackets. Compose evaluates/does only the parentheses in a block.

Comment: Missing or extra brackets can easily be seen by good IDEs. Even otherwise, once code is working, one should pack away the closing brackets- open them later if some problem needs to be debugged. Of what use are 3 almost empty lines in your answer above.

Comment: Not everyone uses an IDE. A simple editor is always available on different platforms. Why format anew if problems arise?

Comment: We should agree to disagree! I have a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46285290/printing-out-text-of-all-gui-elements-in-red-language