# Printing out text of all GUI elements in Red language

Tags: user-interface, rebol, red

I am trying to print out text from all GUI elements in following code:

```
  sentlist: ["A" "B" "C"]

  main: function [slist] [
      view collect [
          repeat i length? slist [
              keep compose [
                  text (slist/:i)
                  field "" 
                  return ]]
          keep [button "Printall" [
              repeat i (2 * length? slist)[
                  print face/parent/pane/(i)/text  ]]]]]

 (main sentlist)
```

It runs all right without any error and `text` elements' text are properly printed out, but for `fields`, only last field's entry is printed out for each field. Where is the problem and how can it be corrected? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your spec `field ""` reuses the same string to each of the fields. Changing one field changes the text for each (likely for efficiency reasons, this is not reflected in the GUI). You could change the line to `field (copy "")` to provide a unique string.

Comment: This is truly a unique problem in this language! Why is it there?

Comment: @rnso The Rebol author wrote about it here: [Is Rebol a Pure Functional Language?](http://www.rebol.com/article/0206.html) and is discussed here: [Is Rebol a Functional Programming Language?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187800/is-rebol-a-functional-programming-language).

Comment: The [Ren-C](https://github.com/metaeducation/ren-c) branch of Rebol 3 locks series that are created literally in source so you would receive an error in the above case.

Comment: @rnso [Many people have complained about this](http://www.rebolforum.com/index.cgi?f=printtopic&topicnumber=31&archiveflag=archive).  A lot of ideas have floated around but the nature of Rebol/Red design makes it hard to excise.  Bear in mind it's not just STRING!s with this behavior, it's deeply nested source blocks.  Strategies like copy-on-write have been considered but bring a loss of control while introducing their own problems.  My own belief evolved to think that sticking with explicit copying -but- locking source by default is the most reasonable answer.

Comment: @HostileFork : Agreed. I have removed my comment.